# Installing vmware-player on Damn Small Linux

Tags: vmware-player

I want to install the player only, not the the vmdk or vmx creator on a Damn Small Linux distro. Is this possible?

Or is there a DSL.iso with vmplayer pre-installed?

Comment: Did you try to download the vmplayer from vmware? 
  https://www.vmware.com/tryvmware/p/activate.php?p=player&lp=default 
I installed the player and the server (v1.x) few years ago on a SuSE Linux and it was working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are it may not be possible - vmware has some drivers - for networking for example - on the host system that are VERY unlikely to be compatible with the... frankly antiquated 2.4 kernel that DSL has. I would be surprised if anything other than QEMU worked.

You can bring a donkey to water, but he ain't winning the grand nationals anytime soon.

Get a distro with a 2.6 or 3.0 kernel , before even considering virtualisation